# Query for searching if part of text is not distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query searching for some specific text in a column and get all the rows containing this text. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve in the below SQL query? I want to find all the places in the text where it says something with name followed by a distinct name, which is really what I want to search for, but I don't know beforehand what this name is, but I do know it's together with the name in the text.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM some_table WHERE xml LIKE '%name="name">[value to search for]%'
```

Such that if I had an XML looking like this:

```
<name = "name">Bob</>
<name = "name">Alice</>
<name = "name">Bob</>
```

It would return the rows where the text column contains Bob and Alice as below. Any hints greatly appreciated.

```
<name = "name">Bob</>
<name = "name">Alice</>
```

Comment: Do you want just the name part of the string, or the whole value?

Comment: I'd like to be able to search for just the value.

Comment: Which value? Specify the expected result as formatted text.

Comment: I've updated the OP.

Comment: As simple as `SELECT DISTINCT xml FROM ...`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Group By   

 SELECT DISTINCT name FROM some_table WHERE xml LIKE '%name="name">[value to search for]%' GROUP BY name
```

Comment: But he neds some kind of generic SQL querry, his SQL querry isnt yet valid. He is looking for some kind of regex which will retrive value from stored strings ... but thats not what SQL, and DBS is made for

Comment: Yeah, what @Take_Care_ mentioned. I've also been thinking that it's not really possible to do with SQL, but I was hoping there might have been something I've overlooked.

Comment: Why GROUP BY without aggregate functions? (Not needed anyway when SELECT DISTINCT.)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this query can give you out your desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM some_table WHERE xml LIKE CONCAT('%name="name">' + name + '</>%')
```

It will return all DISTINCT names which are there in `xml` column.

UPDATE:

> The answer is very simple – the equivalent function in SQL Server to CONCAT() is '+' (plus operator without quotes).

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM some_table WHERE xml LIKE '%name="name">', name ,'</>%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, though it says '+' is not a valid input for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM some_table WHERE xml like CONCAT('%<name = "name">%', name,'</>%')
```